# Does concurrency runtime leaking memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, memory-leaks, mfc

I started a new MFC project with visual studio 2015 and added a simple function with parallel_for that sums up all the numbers from 1 to 100 and included vld.h (Visual Leak Detector) in order to detect memory leaks source. To my surprise, when i closed the program i saw over 200 memory leaks in the output window. 
The troubling code is:

```
std::atomic<int> sum = 0;

void CChildView::RunTask()
{
    parallel_for(1, 101, [&](int i)
    {
        sum += i;
    });

    TRACE(L"\nSum = %d", sum); 
}
```

I also noticed in the task manager that the program memory is growing, so it's a real problem. What am i missing here? i know that this is a legit technology so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: _i saw over 200 memory leaks_ and where was it allocated?

Comment: Hi manni66, it looks like the memory was allocated over the heap: ---------- Block 204 at 0x01376EF0: 60 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    d:\th\minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp (359): ConcurrencyCheck.exe!heap_alloc_dbg_internal + 0x12 bytes

Comment: It is just very late releasing memory it needs to do its job.  Important, it wants to be sure that it is no longer going to be used.  A not-so-great tool like VLD is likely to step in too soon.  Focus on leaks caused by your own code to get ahead, give Application Verifier a spin.

Comment: Hans, but how do i know that this memory will be released eventually? if i run this code over and over i see that the program memory usage is growing in the task manager. Can you recommend a better tool than vld?

Comment: We have no idea, what *"memory"* you are looking at in Task Manager. Chances are, that you are misinterpreting the number, looking at the wrong number, or don't know how to properly read it. Anyway, MFC has builtin memory leak facilities. You don't need to use any other tools. If you do want other tools, Hans Passant already pointed you at an alternative.

Comment: I take a look at the "processes" tab and watching the Memory over there and it seems to be growing if i call RunTask() function multiple times. Is there a way for me to be sure that there are no leaks in my current settings using VLD?  I will also try application Verifier, thanks for the tip Hans.

Comment: Do you know, what that column displays? You should probably read [Make Sense of Memory Management and Key Memory Measurements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382715.aspx) for a quick overview.

Comment: IInspectable, we are talking about the Physical memory that each process is currently using. How is that any different then what i said? if a process is using more and more memory it means that it is allocating/using more memory. Anyway, it is not helping.

Comment: The code doesn't seem correct to me, looking at the ( ) { } etc.?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the edit. The brackets are fine, it's the lambda expression syntax that is so confusing. I promise you that this code compiles and running on my machine.

Comment: Reduce to the Max: Create a Minimal, complete and verifiable code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).